# How to make an label opaque when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like that each option selected on the four lines change to opaque when clicked. Also I need to hide the radio. Sorry for my poor english "/

See here: http://leagueipsum.blogspot.com.br/p/boosting_1.html

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a little CSS--you'll need to take the `opacity:0.5` off of `#wrapper label` and put it on the children, and add the opacity change to the children on `:hover` and `:checked`, like so:

```
#wrapper label {
    opacity: 1;
}

    #wrapper label input,
    #wrapper label span,
    #wrapper label img {
        opacity:0.5;
    }

    #wrapper label:hover input,
    #wrapper label:hover span,
    #wrapper label:hover img {
        opacity:1;
    }

    #wrapper label input:checked{
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    #wrapper label input:checked + span,
    #wrapper label input:checked + img {
        opacity:1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot! I didn't even glimpse that possibility. I'm just a sympathizer of those languages, I hope to devote myself to them someday! It took me all day doing this silly page because I need to study a little of everything that I need to build it. In addition to always keeping myself avoiding the javascript ^^. I hope to learn new things around here!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is absolutely position the `input` off the screen and use the `:checked` pseudo selector and `+` adjacent sibling selector to toggle the opacity of the `label`, like so:

**HTML**

```
<input id="radio" type="radio">
<label for="radio">Label</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=radio]{
    left:-9999px;
    position:absolute;
}
label{
    opacity:.75;
}
:checked+label{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I combined both answers and now is exactly like I wanted! I just don't like to use javascript, I always try to find a way to solve this kind of issues with css.

Comment: You may not yet be able to vote, but, if one of the answers posted here has answered your question to your satisfaction, you can accept it.